# Batch convert Word .docx files to Pages

Tags: ms-office, pages

I have a folder of almost 100 Word documents that I need to edit in Pages, but opening as .docx and then having to save as .pages manually isn't very convenient. Thus, I want to run a script/tool that will convert all of these Word docs to Pages format once and for all.

So far, I've tried these:

- [Docxtor](https://docxtor.de), which works perfectly but only converts 10 documents before presenting a paywall
- [iWork Converter](http://tyorex.com/iWorkConverter), which doesn't do anything when you drag files to the window
- Various Automator and AppleScript scripts, none of which have worked

I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm not keen to purchase Docxtor (if I even could, the Purchase button on the website gives a Paddle error), but this may be the only solution.

I'm running macOS 12 Monterey beta on an M1 MacBook Pro.

If anyone's got any suggestions, I'd be greatly appreciative! Thanks :)

**Update:** I noticed that I misinterpreted iWork Converter, and it's actually for doing the opposite. Nonetheless, I'm still a little stuck here!

Answer (score 3):

I do not have **macOS Monterey** or an **M1** to test on, however, the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

**The use of this *script* requires some initial setup for it to work.**

1. Place all **.docx** *documents* in their own *folder* so the target *folder* can be selected when the *script* runs. A *list* of all the **.docx** *documents* in the target *folder* will be created to *loop* through.
2. Open **Pages** and create a blank *document*, saving it in the *folder* you want the other *documents* saved to, and then minimize it. This is to allow **Pages** to say open while opening and closing the target *documents*, thus making the overall process take less time. No other **Pages** *documents* should be opened. When naming the *document* make it something that is not within the *names* of the other *documents* to be processed.
3. Open **Script Editor** and copy and paste the *example* **AppleScript** *code* into a new *document*, click the **Compile** button (a hammer icon) or press **⌘K** to make sure there are not any compile related issues.
4. Click the **Run** button (right-pointing triangle icon) or press: **⌘R**

### Let the *script* run uninterrupted until it's finished (or errors).

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
property theWordDocumentsList : missing value
property |Pages| : name of ¬
    application id "com.apple.iWork.Pages"

--  # Choose the target folder containing
--  # the docx documents for processing.    

tell application id "com.apple.finder" to ¬
    set theWordDocumentsList to ¬
        (files of container (choose folder) ¬
            whose name extension is "docx") ¬
            as alias list

--  # Loop through: theWordDocumentsList 

repeat with thisDocument in theWordDocumentsList
    
    --  # Open the document.
    
    tell application id "com.apple.iWork.Pages"
        activate
        open thisDocument
    end tell
    
    --  # Give a moment for 'Opening "filename.docx"…' to appear.
    
    delay 0.2
    
    tell application id "com.apple.systemevents"
        
        --  # Wait for 'Opening "filename.docx"…' to disappear.
        
        repeat while (role description of ¬
            UI element 4 of window 1 of ¬
            application process |Pages|) is "button"
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        
        --  # Click 'Save As… ⌥⇧⌘S' to save as a Pages document.
        
        key code 1 using {shift down, option down, command down}
        
        --  # Wait for the 'Save' button to be available.
        
        repeat until exists ¬
            button "Save" of sheet 1 of window 1 of ¬
            application process |Pages|
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        
        --  # Press the 'Save' button.
        
        key code 36 --  # enter key
        
        --  # Wait for the 'Save' button to to disappear.
        
        repeat while exists ¬
            button "Save" of sheet 1 of window 1 of ¬
            application process |Pages|
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        
    end tell
    
    --  # Close the document.
    
    delay 0.2
    tell application id "com.apple.iWork.Pages" to close document 1
    delay 0.5
    
end repeat

--  # Notify user processing if finished.

tell current application to activate
display alert "Processing finished!…"
```

**Notes:**

As the *script* uses **UI Scripting** it can be *kludgy* and prone to failure for a number of different reasons. For example, changes in the **UI** from one version of **macOS** to another or the target *application*. Trying to multi-task while it's running, which is a no-no for this type of *script*! The *value* of the `delay` *commands* outside of the `repeat` *loops* need adjusting.

I tested with a 10 *document* sample set with the *documents* ranging from 1 to 7 pages and on my system, a 16" 2019 **MacBook Pro** 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9, and it took less than 40 seconds. This would equate to ~6.5 minutes for 100 *documents*. Obviously this will vary based on size of the *documents* and the speed of the system it's run on.

You can always test with, or run in several groups, with a smaller number of *documents*.

Although it could be added, I did not include any *error handling* around existing *documents* if the *script* fails and needs to be restarted, so be aware that the **.docx** *documents* which have already been converted need to be manually removed before starting the *script* again.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>